# Converting Image form 300 DPI to 72 DPI an resize with and height

Tags: php, image-resizing, dpi

I'm looking for a solution in php to convert my images from 300 DPI to 72 DPI.
So that the script check first if img == 72 DPI do nothing else convert to 72 DPI. And after that check size and resize image.

Something like this.

```
if ($image(dpi) > 72 dpi) {
   convert to 72 DPI;
}
else {
}
```

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick module or can you install it?

Comment: No. But i have a look at the module and how to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert an image to a different resolution you need ImageMagick.

```
$img = new Imagick($imgname);
if ($img) {
  $width=$img->getImageWidth();
  $height=$img->getImageHeight();
  $res=$img->getImageResolution();
  $colorspace=$img->getImageColorspace();

  $resx=$res['x'];
  $resy=$res['y'];
  echo 'Image is '.$width.'x'.$height.' resolution: '.$resx.'x'.$resy.' colorspace='.$colorspace.'='.$colorspace_array[$colorspace];
  $cmw=($width/$resx)*2.54;
  $cmh=($height/$resy)*2.54;
  echo 'Image is '.$cmw.'cm x '.$cmh.'cm';

  // creating 72dpi version
  $w72=round($width*72/$resx);
  $h72=round($height*72/$resy);
  if ($w72>$width || $h72>$height) {
    $w72=$width;
    $h72=$height;
  }

  $img->resizeImage($w72,$h72,imagick::FILTER_QUADRATIC,1);
  $img->writeImage('newimage.png');

} else {
  die('Unknown image format');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below line of code to convert image dpi from 300 to 72 dpi :

```
$filename = "Enter path of the image which you want to use";
```

> $image = file_get_contents($filename);
>   $image =substr_replace($image, pack("cnn", 1, 72, 72), 13, 5);
>   file_put_contents($filename,$image);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
$image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
$image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

imagejpeg($source_image, $destination_image, $quality); //i'd say keep quality up to 70. anything over that is too much for no reason
```

My suggestion is simply limit the upload size and your problem is solved.

But to answer your question, using ImageMagick:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->setResolution(25,25);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: I have limit the upload :) But thats the problem, they don't understand why the need to convert image. So i was thinking about to make it easy as possible for them :)